# iOS - unable to remove memory leak

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsmutabledictionary

In my TaggingScreen.m init function, I do -

```
tags = [myTagMgr getMyTags];
```

In my getMyTags method, I do the following -

```
NSMutableDictionary *myTags = [NSMutableDictionary new];
....
return myTags;
```

I get a memory leak for myTags in this method. Where should I release the memory? "tags" is a property which is used throughout the TaggingScreen class. So if I do an autorelease, I get an exception saying "message sent to deallocated instance" when I try to access tags in other methods of the class.

**EDIT:**

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)getMyTags
{

NSMutableDictionary *myTags=[NSMutableDictionary new];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tag" 
                                inManagedObjectContext:localObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedArrayObjects = [localObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if (fetchedArrayObjects ==nil) {
    return nil;
}   
if ([fetchedArrayObjects count]==0) {
    return nil;
}   

Tag *aMessage; 
for (int i=0; i<[fetchedArrayObjects count];i++) 
{
    aMessage= (Tag *)[fetchedArrayObjects objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)i];

    [myTags setValue:[aMessage isSet] forKey:[aMessage tagName]];
    }
return myTags;
}
```

Comment: What kind of `@property` is `tags`??

Comment: its a @property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableDictionary *tags;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vignesh and Vin's solutions are correct, but based on what you've said, the best thing to do would be to change `tags` into a `strong` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *tags;
```

Unless you're in a situation where a retain loop might arise (say, a delegate object), you should use `strong` so your properties aren't deallocated from under you.

In addition, unless you're using ARC, you'll want to autorelease `myTags`:

```
return [myTags autorelease];
```

Oh, and if you're not using ARC, you'll want to make sure to release `tags` in `dealloc`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm wrong, but if you use ARC you cannot call autorelease.

Comment: You're right, and I'll mention that. But if the OP is using ARC, they're ignoring a warning about assigning to a weak property.

Comment: I tried this and it works fine the first time I go into the TaggingScreen. But if I go back and re-enter the screen it crashes where I have to access tags. The exception is the same, "message sent to deallocated instance". Could you advise what's going on here?

Comment: Can you post the code for your `getMyTags` method? On second thought it's possible that you shouldn't autorelease `myTags` before returning it.

Comment: Hmm, that all looks fine, and the `autorelease` should definitely be in there. Do you override either the getter or setter for `tags`?

Answer (score 1):

if you do it in `init` method you can do the following:

```
tags = [[myTagMgr getMyTags] retain];
```

instead in your `getMyTags` method

```
return [myTags autorelease];
```

In this manner you have +1 for your `NSDictionary` and you can access it with `self.tags` within your controller.

where

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary* tags;
```

Remember to release it in `dealloc`

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [tags release]; tags = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

P.S. I'm assuming you don't use ARC.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
return [myTags autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `autorelease` in the method. If you need it you will have to `retain` it where you call it.

```
tags = [[myTagMgr getMyTags] retain];
```